# How to Load Balance Websocket Apps. in Docker Swarm?

Tags: websocket, docker-swarm

I have a chat application that I want to scale in a docker swarm. I am also using redis to manage app. state.

I have created a cluster of 3 nodes

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox node1 // master
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox node2 // worker
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox node3 // worker
```

One overlay network (for service-to-service communication)

```
docker network create --driver overlay webnet
```

Two services

```
docker service create --name redis --network webnet --replicas 1 redis:alpine
docker service create --name chatapp --replicas=4 --network webnet --publish 80:3000 anandkr/chatapp-prod
```

**The Problem**

Swarm load-balancer uses round-robin technique to distribute requests on port 80 between the 4 chatapp containers which uses websockets for client communication. Because of this the websocket handshake breaks as there is no stickiness between one client-container.

Even if I use an external load-balancer, it still will offload the responsibility to the swarm load-balancer for service discovery.

How to handle this scenario? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Swarm defaults to using a virtual ip (endpoint-mode vip). So each service gets its own IP address, and the swarm load balancer (which is on OSI layer 4) assigns the request as it sees fit. to prevent a service from having an IP address, you can run
    docker service update webnet --endpoint-mode dnsrr
this will allow an internal load balancer to run a DNS query against a service name, to discover each task/container's IP for a given service.

From there you can do your own load balancing (probably hash ip)
if you are doing that, you need to make sure you have the clients IP available to the load balancer (have the x-forwarded-for header set *before* a vm or docker gateway.